# Tabular output in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to make tabular output in Ruby...

I am using `puts "x\t\t[OK]`

assuming that x represents inputted filename, and this process is repeated for ever, and assuming that the range of characters is from 5 - 20 characters the output won't be neat

Output sample: http://pastebin.com/kwJ9ajqj

I want the OKs to be aligned.

Comment: This should be on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'd think the issue is that the tabs are starting from different column numbers because of longer and shorter filenames. Could you change it to `puts [OK]\t\tx` so that the OKs line up and the filenames start at the same column?

Comment: it's a good solution. but I am running a processes analyzer so it should be like... Process name \t\t [ok]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fill the x-s with spaces to the same (maximum) length using ljust.

```
xs = [ "short", "longer string", "even a bit longer" ]
xs.each { | x | puts "#{x.ljust(20)} [OK]" }
```

This will align the "[OK]"s. If you need tabs, you can insert them 
after filling like

```
puts "#{x.ljust(20)}\t\t[OK]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use printf-style formatting:

```
printf("%20s  %s", filename, (ok ? '[OK]' : '[FAILED]'))
```